# I use the same code on different google sheet but the date format is different. How is it possible?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm facing a little problem. I'm using google sheet and google appscript to send email to customers. However when I use the same code on two different sheets the date format in the mail title changes.

One will give me

```
Facture Osteo n° 14752 du 27/06/2022
```

and the other (the wrong one)

```
Facture Osteo n°14752 du Mon Jun 27 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
```

To create the email I use data from a sheet and it replace data in an another sheet used to generate the invoice.

I checked the settings in the google sheet I don't see any issue with it, same timezone and country.

Anyone one as an idea?

```
function Facturereview2() {
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var data=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var currRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
  var i=currRow-1
  var donneesFacture=data[i];
  var doc=app.openById("1zGzIrT8AT0rGRfYR-qIOYJt-lB_IGLvSyh3BWPjKlxU")
  var Facture = doc.getSheetByName("Facture");
  Facture.getRange(2,4).setValue(donneesFacture[1]);
  Facture.getRange(11,4).setValue(donneesFacture[2]);
  Facture.getRange(13,5).setValue(donneesFacture[0]);
  Facture.getRange(19,7).setValue(donneesFacture[3]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var pdf=doc.getAs('application/pdf');
    var file=DriveApp.createFile(pdf);
    DriveApp.removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()));
    
const HTMLTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Facture review")
const HTMLforemail = HTMLTemplate.evaluate().getContent()

    var email=donneesFacture[9]
    var sujet="Facture Osteo n°"+donneesFacture[1]+" du "+donneesFacture[2]; // donneesFacture[2] is the date
    var texte="Veuillez trouver ci attachée votre note d'honoraire du "+donneesFacture[2]+".\nText,\n\n Text";
    var option={
      htmlBody:HTMLforemail,
      attachments:file
    };
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email,sujet,texte, option);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `.getValues()` with `.getDisplayValues()` to get all data, including dates, as text strings in the format they show in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thx, didn't know you could do that. That was great way to solve my problem.